# Fast RSA encryption in AS3

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, apache-flex, cryptography, rsa

I have a Flex 4 application that uses a 2048 bits private RSA key to encrypt/sign some string values that are around 30 characters long.

I'm currently using the com.hurlant.crypto.RSAKey implementation to do so but I'm facing the following limitations:

- It takes way too long (around 4 seconds for signing a 30 chars
  string)
- The UI freezes while the class is processing (implementation obviously doesn't
  use events or chunks processing)

I have been looking for other libraries but I haven't found so far any other with the same level of  functionalities (read RSA key from PEM string, allow RSA.sign(), RSA.encrypt and decrypt), that is free to use in commercial applications and that is faster than the one I currently use.

So my questions are:

- Does anyone know a great/fast AS3 library that do that?
- If there are none and I decide to write one myself from scratch will I be
  facing the same problems because the low performances are somehow induced by the
  flash platform ?

**EDIT2**: Below code uses a PEM encoded private key stored in a file. If you don't have one you can create one using the following piece of code:

```
var exp:String = "10001";
var bits:int = 2048;
rsa = RSAKey.generate(bits, exp);
```

Don't forget to sit down and take a coffee as it takes nearly one minute to generate.

**EDIT**: Here is piece of code showing the limitations.
Simply click on the start button and see how the progress bar and the application completely freezes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.hurlant.crypto.rsa.RSAKey;
            import com.hurlant.util.der.PEM;

            import mx.utils.Base64Encoder;

            var pkfilePath:String = "/Users/david/Desktop/private_key.pem"; 
            var stringToSign:String = "Hello this is a string to be signed by an efficient AS3 library";

            private function readPKContent():String {
                var f:File = new File(pkfilePath);
                var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
                fs.open(f,FileMode.READ);
                var rawKey:String = fs.readUTFBytes(fs.bytesAvailable);
                fs.close();
                return rawKey;
            }

            private function logTime(msg:String, start:Date, end:Date):void {
                resultTA.text = msg + " " + (end.time-start.time) + " ms\n" + resultTA.text; 
            }

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                cryptWithHurlant();
            }

            private function cryptWithHurlant():void {
                var start:Date = new Date();

                //Load key and use it to sign something
                var rawPK:String = readPKContent();
                var time:Date = new Date();
                var rsa:RSAKey = PEM.readRSAPrivateKey(rawPK);
                logTime("Hurlant:ReadRSA", time, new Date());

                //Compute a signature of the string
                var srcBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                srcBA.writeUTFBytes(stringToSign);

                //Now sign inside the second BA
                var desBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                time = new Date();
                rsa.sign(srcBA, desBA, srcBA.length);
                logTime("Hurlant:Encrypt", time, new Date());

                //desBA.position = 0;
                //Recover as a Base64 response
                //var b64encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
                //time = new Date();
                //b64encoder.encodeBytes(desBA);
                //logTime("Base64:Encoded "+b64encoder.toString(),time, new Date());

                logTime("Hurlant:Total",start,new Date());
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="Start"/>
        <mx:ProgressBar indeterminate="true"/>
        <s:TextArea width="100%" height="100%" editable="false" id="resultTA"/>
    </s:VGroup>


</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: I edited your question to remove some "flame-bait" style commentary about Flash performance.  Flash is pretty good at what it does and it has gotten better in the past 3 years.  In many cases it is better performing than alternatives.  To solve you're problem, my first impulse is to recommend trying to optimize the Hurlant Crypto library; but not being an expert on encryption I couldn't tell you how.  A code sample demoing the performance limitations you're experiencing may help here.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com This commentary was indeed not really constructive and a little off-topic. Let's put it to the fact that I spent a week supporting customers because of Adobe's last big mistake (latest air runtime release simply completely emptied the encrypted local store leading to the loss of the private key and licence information that were stored inside)... Anyway, back to the topic I have added a little piece of code showing the problem.

Comment: Why do you need RSA encryption? Maybe you could use another algorithm depending on what you really need...

Comment: @Florent Strong RSA encryption is a prerequisite on the back-end server so I must use it (as I already do in other client applications not written in AS3).

Comment: Edit the library and make it chunk the encryption on a timer. Or looking into threading it.

Comment: @The_asMan Yeah I thought of using a timer or events as it will make the application more responsive but in the end it will take even longer. Anyway I guess that's why I will do if I don't find any other solution. Regarding multi-threading it's impossible in flash (single threaded runtime).

Comment: @Davz If you can use Flash Player 11.4/AIR 3.4 concurrency is now an option via [Workers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html).

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2 thanks for the link I wasn't aware of that. Even if I still don't know if I will make AIR 3.4 a prerequisite for my app  I think I will anyway give it a try as it sounds to be a great feature. Only drawback is that it's not supported for mobile platforms.

Comment: @Davz I've only toyed with it but I found it to be a nice feature. Definitely want to use Flash Builder 4.7 (currently in beta on Adobe Labs) as it provides tooling for creating and debugging workers. Word is that it will hit mobile eventually (next release maybe?).

Comment: @Davz You may want to look into this timer based "threading" implementation. This wont speed anything up but it will get rid of UI lock. I have code using this working on mobile. http://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/threads-in-as3-flex-actionscript/

Comment: Based on all that has been said in comments and the absence of answers I think that my best option for now will be to edit the RSA implementation to make it able to run with the pseudo-threading model proposed by f-a. I will move to workers once they will be supported by mobile platforms. I will post some code in answer when it will be done but not before two weeks because I'm now in holidays ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> You may want to look into this timer based "threading" implementation. This won't speed anything up, but it will get rid of the UI lock. I have code using this working on mobile.
>
> Based on all that has been said in comments and the absence of answers, I think that my best option for now will be to edit the RSA implementation to make it able to run with the pseudo-threading model proposed by f-a. I will move to workers once they are supported by mobile platforms.

**References**

- [Threads in ActionScript 3](http://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/threads-in-as3-flex-actionscript/)
- [flash.system.Worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)